# React Native: How to keep multi-line textinput visible above keyboard

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, textinput

I have a TextInput with multiline set to true. 
I am scrolling to the input on focus with:

```
scrollResponder.scrollResponderScrollNativeHandleToKeyboard(
  React.findNodeHandle(this.refs.myInput),
  0,
  true
);
```

However when the multiline TextInput expands the text will be hidden beneath the keyboard.
I only want to scroll down when the cursor/current text is not visible. So I can't just run the code above on text change as it would scroll the view even if the current cursor/current text is visible (like editing on the first line).

Is there any way to get the cursor/current text position on screen?
Or is there any other way to do what I'm trying to?

Currently:

[image]

What I'm trying to achieve: 
[image]

Comment: @S Kraft. Many years later. Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

You may use the [onLayout](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view.html#onlayout) method, provided by the View (which Text extends). It returns the dimensions of the view, which you may use to recalculate the scroll position of your scrollview.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be called when text is added to the TextInput

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do it seems to be with the react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view library and use the method [_scrollToInput](https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view#programatically-scroll-to-any-textinput) and follow what the docs say.

[image]

The one thing I had to change was to call "this.scroll.props.scrollToFocusedInput(reactNode)" instead of "this.scroll.scrollToFocusedInput(reactNode)" in the docs!

Answer (score 0):

I found this component... but it's not working for me (I get errors on "import"). I assume that they will get fixed eventually.

https://github.com/VansonLeung/react-native-keyboard-aware-view